# I am using ContextAPI in a React Application but I am not able access the states with correct values in components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-context

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getQuestionDetails();
    getAnswers();
}, []);
```

I am using the above `useEffect` hook in a react functional component, I am calling to async functions which fetch data using axios  from server. I use some state values in context API as payload in the http requests of axios . for the first render I am getting the values of states from context properly but after that values are not proper. not only the functions inside `useEffect` but one more function outside `useEffect` also not able to get corrects state value

#### This is the first ever render where some payload values are taken from context API:

[image: This is the first ever render where some payload values are taken from context api]

#### This is after I reloaded the same page, I am not getting values from context:

[image: This is after I reloaded the same page, I am not getting values from context]

I am trying to get the correct values of states from context API for every render, but I am getting the correct values only for the first ever render but after that when I reload the page initial values which were assigned while creating states are coming.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    getQuestionDetails();
    getAnswers();
});
```

Use the hook like that.
The reason is the '[]' in the hook parameters.
It sajs that reinvoke the hook only if [] is different than [].